# testing vuex action in mounted lifecycle method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I'm trying to test that a vuex action is called when a component is mounted, but I can't. this is my code:

```
...
describe('ReservationsList.vue Test', () => {  
  
  let actions
  let getters
  let store
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {

    actions = {
      fetchReservations: jest.fn()
    }

    getters = {      
      reservationsList: () => reservationsData.data
    }

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      actions,
      getters     
    })                     

  }) 

  describe('store', ()=>{

    it('calls store action "fetchReservations" when mounted', async () => {                  

      wrapper = shallowMount(ReservationsList, {
        store, 
        localVue
      });     
      await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();          
      expect(actions.fetchReservations).toHaveBeenCalled()                 

    })  

  })
})
```

But the tests fails:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

this is my ReservationsList Component:

```
<template>  
  <div class="reservations-list card o-hidden mb-4">
      <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center border-0">
          <h3 class="w-50 float-left card-title m-0">Reservations</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
          <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table text-center" id="user_table">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th scope="col">Name</th>
                          <th scope="col">Email</th>
                          <th scope="col">Booking date</th>
                          <th scope="col">Number of guests</th>                     
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>                       

                    <reservations-item 
                      :key="reservation.id"
                      v-for="reservation in reservationsList" 
                      :reservation="reservation"                      
                      >                        
                    </reservations-item>    
                                                                 
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>          
      </div>
  </div>                  
</template>
<script>
    
    import ReservationsItem from './ReservationsItem';
    import {mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex';
    import { fetchReservations } from "../store/actions.type";
    import store from "../store";

    export default {       

      components: { ReservationsItem },

      mounted(){      
        this.fetch();
      },

      computed:{
        ...mapGetters(['reservationsList'])                
      },           

      methods: {        
        fetch() {            
            store.dispatch('fetchReservations');
        }
    }

  }
</script>
```

And my Vuex store:

```
....
export const actions = {  
    
    fetchReservations({commit}, url){

       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        return axios.get(url).then(({data})=>{             
             commit(SET_RESERVATIONS, data.data);
             resolve(true);     
         }).catch(error => {             
             commit(SET_ERROR, error.response.data.message);
             reject(true);
      });   

    });

    }
}

.....
```

The code is working fine, but the test fails, I am using vue-test-utils version 1.1.2 and jest version 26.6.3,  What can I do? Thank you

Comment: It looks fine to me also. Did you try to debug it?

Comment: yes but still the test doesn't pass, I have seen that in React, when testing an action in a  lifecycle method, they explicity call it explicity like this: wrapper.instance().componentDidMount() , but in Vue I don't know how to do it